# How to change multiple panel images with a numeric up-down?

Tags: vb.net

I have over 100 panels that scroll in a tab control. I have a code that changes the panels background image with and open file dialog, I also have a numeric up down control which lets me select by number which panels image I want to change.

```
Try
    If NumericUpDown1.Value = 2 Then
        If OpenFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then
            Panel5.BackgroundImage = New Bitmap(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
        End If
    End If
Catch ex as exception
finally
End Try
```

I don't want to keep writing this code for all the panels since their are over 100 panels, does anyone know how this can be accomplished in a shorter fashion, maybe a 'For Each' code that might work.

Comment: you could make a procedure passing the relevant data to it from whereever it is needed.  The empty catch is quite dubious.  If you dont care enough to even report the catastrophe, why trap for it?

Comment: And that is the reason for the open file dialog. I could have just set it's image and not worry about it, but it is connected to a database, thanks for the clue but the need to pass the procedure is open and could be triggered at any time, so far anything I've tried outside the Numeric up down control will lead to a case by case basis, but there needs to be a shorter procedure to cover all a panels.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want set image to only one picture box at the time, but not write code for all.

```
Class MyForm
    Inherits Form

    private _selectedPanel as Panel

    Public Sub New()


        ' here wire handler
        Dim p as Panel
        For Each c as control in Me.Controls
            pb = TryCast(c, Panel)
            If p IsNot Nothing Then
                AddHandler p.Click,  AddressOf Panel_Click 
        next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Panel_Click(sender as Object, e as EventArgs)
         _selectedPanel = DirectCast(sender, Panel)

    End Sub


    Private Sub SomeMethod()


       Try
           If NumericUpDown1.Value = 2 Then
               If OpenFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then
                   _selectedPanel.BackgroundImage = New Bitmap(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
               End If
           End If
       Catch ex as exception
            MessageBox.Show("oops:" & ex.Message)
       End Try 


   End Sub

End Class
```

This way you click on the panel you want to change image for and then you click on your up/down to do it.

Now, how you mark the active panel - this is different issue. You can have a hidden control (checkbox for example), which can show up in the corner of the panel to check or uncheck one. I don't know if you need it.

Comment: Thanks, but there has to be more than one panel, as many as possible need to be shown on screen. the tab control is just used to switch between pages, each panel is assigned a number, the numeric up down is used to determine the panel selected, it goes up to 100, each page, their are 8 pages. So if the numeric up down value is "10" that means the panel number is "10". Is their some type of array that can be used to cover this so I would not have to write the method I posted 800 times?

Comment: @TehutiMAAT Can you post the use case. e.g. User clicks on the tab - 10 panels loaded with pictures. etc. What determines number of panels? Do you need to open pictures using the dialog, etc.? Use case should really clear the question. Just now, from your comment I understood that up-down is controlling your tabs and not the Panels

Comment: I'm trying this one out you posted